# Easy way to export Wikipedia's translated titles

Tags: wikipedia

Is there an easy way to export Wikipedia's translated titles to get a set like this: 
`russian_title -> english_title`?

I tried to get ones from
[**ruwiki-latest-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2** and **ruwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2**](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/ruwiki/latest/), however, there are less than 25k translations.

I found out some are not present. E.g. one can see a link to English wiki [here](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yandex), but there is no link `[[en:Yandex]]` in the dump.

Maybe I should try to parse English Wikipedia, but I'm sure there is a nicer solution.

BTW, I'm using [wikixmlj](http://code.google.com/p/wikixmlj/) + tried to find `en:Yandex` with `grep`.

**UPD:** link to @svick's solution data: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/ [language code] wiki/latest/
e.g. http://dumps.wikimedia.org/ruwiki/latest/

Comment: Thanks @Anton . But There are a lot of links on Wikimedia dump downloading page: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/    . I need to process millions english articles (content) and their related articles on spanish and germany language. what files should I downloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the links between Wikipedia articles in various languages is now on [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/). So, if you wanted to get to the source, you could download the dump of Wikidata and parse that (it's in JSON).

But I think a better way would be to use the dump of [the `langlinks` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aLanglinks_table). This contains exactly the information you want, both for links from Wikidata and links that are still in the old form.

This dump is in SQL format. You can import that dump into an MySQL database, or you can parse it directly (I have written [a .Net library that does that](https://github.com/svick/Wikipedia-SQl-dump-parser)).

The table contains mappings from page id of your wiki (in your case the Russian Wikipedia) to page titles in other wikis. This means you will need the page ids of the pages you're interested in. For small number of pages, you can look them up manually using [the “Page information” link](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81&action=info), or you could use the API. But if you need this for large number of pages, you should download the dump of the `page` table, which contains this mapping.

Comment: Seems to solve the problem. Going to write a script in some JVM language. Thank you.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? `$ grep 'Alice' extwiki-20131231-langlinks.sql` returns nothing. Is it the wrong dump?

Comment: @Anton What would you expect that to return? I can't find any pages on extwiki that would contain language link to pages with “Alice” in their title. (And I also can't find any pages on extwiki that would contain “Alice” in their title, but your grep wouldn't find those.)

Comment: I would expect something like `([id], 'en', 'Alice's Adventures in Wonderland')`. I'm looking for **all** wikipedia's title's translations.

Comment: @Anton But there is no article about Alice's Adventures in Wonderland in Extremaduran Wikipedia, so where would that translation come from?

Comment: Stupid me. I wonder how come I bumped into Extremaduran Wiki dump. Now going to scan ruwiki and enwiki. Many thanks. Please pardon the disturbance :)

Comment: I built this sometime ago to help: http://adamhwang.github.io/wikitranslator/ code is open source

Comment: @Adam do you have an API for it ;-) ? EDIT: nvm I did not read the open source part. Looks nice, thanks !

Comment: Dear @Svick. I need to process millions english articles (content) and their related articles on spanish and germany language. what files should I downloads? and how to do that? Thank you.